# Is it possible to use for loop (i.e to print multiple times) in java awt FlowLayout?? I need to print f. Add(b1) 35 times if possible how

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I want to print f. add(b1) ;35 times and the program is below, 
import java.awt.*;

pobe import javax.swing. *:

public class MyFlowLayout(

JFrame f;

MyFlowLayout () {

f=new JFrame ();

JButton bl-new JButton("1");

JButton b2=new JButton ("2");

JButton b3-new JButton ("3");

JButton b4=new JButton ("4");

JButton b5-new JButton ("5");

f.add (bl); f.add (b2); f.add (b3); f.add (b4); f.add (b5);

f.setLayout (new FlowLayout()); //setting flow layout of right alignment

f.setSize (300,300);

f.setVisible(true);

1 public static void main(String[] args) { new MyFlowLayout();

Comment: You mean you are planning to add 35 buttons, and you want a concise way to add them all? Or do you literally just want to print `f.add(b1);` thirty five times to the console?

Comment: Only to print 35 times brother

Comment: I'm very confused.  But `for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) { System.out.println("f.add(b1) ;"); }` should do that?